# Git: Is there a way to delete (locally and remote) all the branches created by me?

Tags: git, git-branch

Is there a script to delete all the branches created by me?

I found questions on stackoverflow and on internet about listing the branches by author, like this

[Is there a script to list git branches created by me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026374/is-there-a-script-to-list-git-branches-created-by-me)

But I could not find anything like delete them.

Is there any way?

I also found one this post for unused branch bulk delete but not by author

[Is there a way to bulk delete git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991695/is-there-a-way-to-bulk-delete-git-branches)

Comment: When you say "delete a branch", do you simply mean that you want to delete the ref, or are you also trying to remove commits?

Comment: Note : the first answer in the linked question is wrong. It does **not** list branches created by X, it lists all branches whose *last commit* is from author X, which is completely different. Metadata about who created a branch is not stored anywhere in git.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - To be honest I am not quite sure about the difference of the two. I basically wants to delete all my created branches because they are merged to the parent branch and are of no use now, so basically the action of the `--delete` command

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7726949/184546).

Answer (score 1):

Git has no idea who created some branch name, so no, this is not possible in general.

> I basically wants to delete all my created branches because they are merged to the parent branch

Branch names do not store parent information either.  You can, however, ask whether the *tip commit* found via some branch name is *contained within* the set of commits found via some other branch name, using `git branch --merged` for instance:

```
git fetch origin
git branch --merged origin/main
```

will list out any of your (local) repository branch names that identify a commit that is contained within the commit-set found by `origin`'s `main` (as last updated by `git fetch`, hence the `git fetch` step first).

[William Pursell asks, in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737865/git-is-there-a-way-to-delete-locally-and-remote-all-the-branches-created-by-m#comment126777868_71737865):

> > When you say "delete a branch", do you simply mean that you want to delete the ref, or are you also trying to remove commits?

Your answer is:

> To be honest I am not quite sure about the difference of the two.

The difference here is the key, because Git is not really about *branches*, but rather about *commits*.  If you are going to use Git at all, you *must* learn about commits.  This will also make Git's branching model make some sense.  Rather than repeat it all here, though, I'll just refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71568500/1256452).